# How should I declare an array?

Tags: python, c++, arrays

This is an example of my function from dll. I understand that I should ignore return value, but how to declare the array in Python to get new array back?

C++ code:

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int* SortFunc(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)     
        for(int j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > arr[j]; j--) 
        {
            int temp = arr[j - 1];
            arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    return arr;
}
```

And I want to use this function in my Python program. Usual discription works if I pass array to the function, but it doesn't work if want to get it back.

```
python_list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 4]
a = (ctypes.c_int * len(python_list))(*python_list)
b = SortFunc(a, n)
print(b[:])
```

When I use this I can see an error: "'int' object is not subscriptable", array b have same discription as array a.

Comment: Your Python code runs fine on my machine.  What error message or undesirable behavior does it produce?  Please include the call to SortFunc as well, since maybe the problem occurs there.

Comment: Oh, I excuce for my inaccuracy. It doesn't work when I want to return the value and print the array. This discription works if I pass array to the function, but it doesn't work if want to get it back.  When I use this `b = SortFunc(a, n)` and try to print it `print(b[:])` I can see an error: "'int' object is not subscriptable", array b have same discription as array a.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful.  Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: What type does C++ think it's returning?  What type does Python think it received?  Print out the type of *arr* just before the return; print out the type of *b* just after.  From your messages, it seems that Python thinks it got an int instead of a list of ints, but let's check that with both run-time systems.

Comment: I have a task to write C++ dll and use it in Python but I never studied it before. That's why I have some troubles with discription of all of it. This program changes array a. It means if I use this function I'll get a sorted array a, it works. But I want to learn how to discribe the array b to a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `SortFunc` modifies `arr` in place.  Does this work?

```
SortFunc(a, n)
print(a[:])  # hopefully this will now show [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10]
```

I think with your current code, `b` may just be an int, perhaps an error flag.  Instead of returning the result, you may need to get the result using pass by reference.  So the Python code would look like:

```
SortFunc(a, b, n)
print(b[:])
```

That would call `void SortFunc(int arr[], int sorted[], int n)`.  There is some code at http://staff.mbi-berlin.de/schultz/Call_C-DLL_from_Python.txt that changes an array by reference.

One more thing: I'm not sure this will work, but you might try returning a new allocated array instead of returning `arr`:

```
int * sorted_array = new int[n];
// Read in values from arr and sort them into sorted_array...
return sorted_array
```

Comment: Yes, it modifies `arr` and it works, but I wanted to return new array. I had an idea to call the function with another array, but I just didn't know how to realize that. Thanks's for the help it was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly is causing you to see that error, although I suspect something is going wrong with how "b" gets created. I am assuming you have a slightly different Python version of your function since Python's syntax won't allow the "for (int i = 0...)" syntax.

That said, I was able to get a properly sorted array back from the following Python implementation of your C function:

```
def sort_func(arr, n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range (i, 0, -1):
            if arr[j-1] > arr[j]:
                temp = arr[j - 1]
                arr[j - 1] = arr[j]
                arr[j] = temp
    return arr
```

which when run using

```
python_list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 4]
a = (ctypes.c_int * len(python_list))(*python_list)
b = sort_func(a, len(python_list))
print(b[:])
```

as input, gives the sorted array [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10] from the call to "print(b[:])".

As a side note, you can achieve the same results by simply calling "sorted(a)", which from what I understand will do the same as your written function.